# How to expand div / show hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to expand the .sort width and show all content in the .sort-expand div. This is expanding to the right with the .sort expanding from 200px when "more" is clicked to 400px. And, when clicked again, to shrink.

```
    <div class="sort">
    <div class="mainimg"></div>
    <div class="infoarea">
        <h3>Main Name</h3>
        <p>Title of position</p>
        <p><span class="floatl">Tag01, Tag02</span><span class="floatr"><a href="#" class="show">more</a></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-expand">
        <div class="votes"></div>
        <div class="full-info"></div>
        <div class="other"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This also needs to push all the other .sort areas so it doesn't overlap them. Any ideas? I will post what I've started with but having a hard time. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).  `.slideDown()` will push the other elements as it animates downwards and shows the content of the div.  Call it on the div you want: `$("#myDiv").slideDown()`  If you want it to shrink when clicked again, use [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: Brilliant, I will try this out then post the code when I get it. Thanks for your help / guidance.